# Factor Scores from CFA

Tags: confirmatory-factor

I want to use factor scores computed from my CFA model to test my hypothesis. I use Maximum Likelihood for CFA and GLS to compute factor scores in EQS. My question is - are the factor scores derived this way supposed to be standardized? The reason I ask this question is I get factor scores that have a mean of 0 but the SD is greater than 1.Hence the confusion.

I just need to confirm if this is normal or I am having an error in my procedure/data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define your model, you have to either fix a factor loading to 1, or the variance of the latent variable/factor to be 1. This is to make the model identifiable.

If you have specified the latent variable/factor variance to be 1, the SD should be 1. However, if you have instead fixed one of the factor loadings to be 1 so the model can be identified, then I don't think the SD has to be 1 (though it certainly could).

If you want the factor scores with variance/SD=1, either set the latent variance to 1 and allow all factor loadings to vary freely, or standardize the factor scores after creating them.